# How to create a test for a pivot table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to create a test for a controller. There are three tables `Roles`, `Categories` and `Categories_roles`, the relation is many to many.

Controller:

```
/**
 * Update connections.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
 */
public function update(Request $request) {
    $input = $request->get('category', []);
    foreach (Category::all() as $category) {
        $category->roles()->sync(Arr::get($input, $category->id, []));
    }

    return view('home');
}
```

I can not figure out how to write a test, I have a vague idea in my head but I don't know how to do it. This is what I have done.

Test:

```
/** @test */
public function test_admin_user_can_edit_categories_roles()
{
    $this->actingAs(\App\Models\User::factory()->create(['role_id' => 1]));

    $input = [
        "1" => [
            "1" => "1"
        ],
        "2" => [
            "1" => "1"
       ],
    ];
    $this->post('/admin/connections', $input);
}
```

Comment: Could you add more info about the input ? What is `$request->get('category', [])` ? Is it an array ? Is it an array of what categories ? I am asking this because I do not see the relation between `categories` and `roles` as you are doing `$category->roles()->sync()`, are you saying that the associated `role` to that `category` is going to have a new value ? Like the input is `1 => 2`, you are saying that `role_id = 1` associated to that category, is now going to be `role_id = 2` ?

Comment: I have a two-dimensional array at the entrance. [1 => [1 => 1], 2 => [1 => 1]]. These data are needed to update connections. [connections](https://i.imgur.com/dCm8D4c.jpg)

Comment: I need some help here as I am getting confused. What does `1 => [1 => 1]` mean ? Is it saying that `role_id = 1`, something `true` ? I do not understand what the first index means `[ 1 ...`, I think that `=> 1]` means you want it set to `true`, right ? If `[1 => 1]` is saying something like `for role_id = 1, have first column set to true`, that is pretty confusing, so explain that and I will be able to help you.

Comment: I have two tables, roles and categories. There is a pivot table roles_categories. 

[Role](https://i.imgur.com/z5AQigb.jpg) (id name), [categories](https://i.imgur.com/4BazJ1G.jpg) (id title), [roles\_categories](https://i.imgur.com/Viwr5Rt.jpg) (roles\_id, categories_id)

When the request comes (two-dimensional array), using the sync() method updated the roles_categories table.

Comment: I think we are confusing things. If you do `roles()->sync([1 => [1 => 1]])` (as the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations) says) you are going to update `role_id = 1` with data `[1 => 1]`, this last part is the one that makes no sense, it would make sense if you sent something like `[1 => ['admin' => 1, 'manager' => 0]]`, but it makes no sense when you send `[1 => 1]`. If you remove that part, is your code still doing what you want ?

Comment: I need to write a feature test to verify the work of my controller. The controller itself works. Forgive me, I'll probably write wrong.

Comment: I know you need to do a test, but if I do not understand what `[1 => 1]` means, I cannot help you do tests as I do not understand that. It makes no sense, it should be `[1 => ['COLUMN' => 'VALUE YOU WANT']]` and not `[1 => [1 => 'whatever value you want']]`. Can you clarify that part ?

Comment: [role_id (1) => [categories_id (1) => categories_id(1)], role_id (2) => [categories_id (1)  => categories_id (1) ]]. One role may have several categories

Comment: That is not how `sync` works. Read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships again. if you do `$category->roles()->sync([1, 2, 3, 4])` it is going to remove all `roles` associated to that `category` and associate new roles, those being `role_id = 1, 2, 3 and 4`. If you pass an array for each index, it will send that data as to edit other columns that row has, if you `categories_roles` has the 2 `id`s and also a column like `automatic`, you should do `[1 => ['automatic' => false, 2 => ['automatic' => true]]`, etc.

Comment: That is why `[role_id(1) => [categories_id(1) => categories_id(1)], role_id(2) => [categories_id(1) => categories_id(1)]]` makes no sense at all. If you want that, you just have to do `$category = Category::find(1)->roles()->sync([1, 2])` and that will assign role `1` and `2` to `category_id = 1`.

Comment: I read it again, and I forgot that you were doing `Arr::get($input, $category->id, [])`, why did this happen to me ? Because you are doing `$input = [1 => [1 => 1], 2 => [1 => 1]]` and you did not send `category`, so `$request->get('category', [])` will always be `[]`... so your code would be `If I find the category id, do [1 => 1]`. So it will still do `->sync([1 => 1])` for `role_id = 1 and 2` and still makes no sense, but at least is better...